# Is it necessary to configure Flurry AppCircle to start receiving ads with basic setup?

Tags: android, flurry

I have followed all integration guide at flurry.com for android, but I'm not receiving any ad. FlurryAgent.getAd allways returns false. And verbose output states -> "Ad request succesful but server delivered no ad units". Documentation states that the only thing to do to start receiving ads is just do the basic setup (Create app and configure ad space for this app), but, I'm starting to wonder if I need to configure the AppCircle tab on flurry.com.

Could anybody help here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get ads on Flurry, you simply need to create an ad space on the Flurry website (dev.flurry.com) and call it inside your code. All the ad space configuration needs to be done under the Publishers tab. AppCircle tab need only be used if you're promoting your app using Flurry.
With regards to ads not showing up, can you please send the following details to support@flurry.com:
1. Flurry SDK version
2. Snippet of integration
3. App name and ad space name
(Full Disclosure: I work in the Support team at Flurry)